# Traffic info distanceMatrix API java client

Tags: google-maps, traffic, google-distancematrix-api

I'm trying to use the java client to get information about duration between 2 city but i need also the duration with traffic information. I'm using the java client 0.1.11 and i only get the duration without traffic information, there is no method about traffic mode so how can i do ?

EDIT : I want to use this part of the documentation : 
traffic_model (defaults to best_guess) which is optional parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation provided by google you can get the "duration_in_traffic" but not the traffic details.And moreover this facility is only available to the google premium plan users.

Read this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_results

The "traffic_model" option can take the following values

trafficModel (optional) specifies the assumptions to use when calculating time in traffic. This setting affects the value returned in the duration_in_traffic field in the response, which contains the predicted time in traffic based on historical averages. Defaults to best_guess.

The following values are permitted:

google.maps.TrafficModel.BEST_GUESS (default) or string value best_guess indicates that the returned duration_in_traffic should be the best estimate of travel time given what is known about both historical traffic conditions and live traffic. Live traffic becomes more important the closer the departureTime is to now..

google.maps.TrafficModel.PESSIMISTIC or string value pessimistic indicates that the returned duration_in_traffic should be longer than the actual travel time on most days, though occasional days with particularly bad traffic conditions may exceed this value.

google.maps.TrafficModel.OPTIMISTIC or string value optimistic indicates that the returned duration_in_traffic should be shorter than the actual travel time on most days, though occasional days with particularly good traffic conditions may be faster than this value.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps Distance Matrix API is design for calculating the distances and the durations of multiple origin and multiple destination.

This api does not return traffic information. Please read the official document (before asking).

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro

Comment: maybe i'm not clear in what i want. Of corse i have already ready the documentation before asking. I paste you the part on the documentation i want : traffic_model (defaults to best_guess) in Optional parameters. How can i use it.